# How does one implement SRV wildcard domains in IPv6?

Tags: dns, bind, ipv6

I was looking to do something similar to

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup#Records_other_than_PTR_records

and place a SRV record in the reverse DNS tree.

In particular I was hoping to be able to add a srv record for a chunk
of the address space by using a wildcard.  Something like the
following....

_service._tls.*.26.19.in-addr.arpa. IN SRV 1 1 443 service.example.com

However it turns out that my understanding of wildcard domains was inadequate according to:

SRV RRSet at a Wildcard Domain Name
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4592#section-4.5

The above is confusing but basically explains (I think) that my
single wildcard SRV record above won't work.  I think I need a SRV
record for each and every ip address I wanted to cover with the
wildcard domain.

In IPv4 I know I can use things like Bind's $GENERATE directive to automate the creation of all the records.  But how would something like this be handled in IPv6 particularly if I also wanted to use DNSSEC to have all the records signed?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use a single wildcard record, but it cannot coexist with other records and must be "\*", not "whatever._tcp.\*". I suspect that the proper answer your question is to step back and base your code on another foundation, perhaps DHCPv6, because the IPv6 privacy extensions are deployed and will conflict with per-address configuration.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply.  I don't understand your comment completely however, SRV records always take the following form: "_service._proto.name. TTL class SRV priority weight port " see target.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record.  The name component is where wildcards would be applied.  Yes, I did consider alternative implementations using things like DHCP but have a very particular reason for wanting to implement this using SRV records.  Thanks again.

Comment: SRV records always take that form, but the asterisk-related code doesn't know that. It only knows the general DNS rules. A DNS server that receives a query for "foo" does two things: First look up foo. If there are no records for foo in the zone, it looks up "\*". The asterisk is not a wildcard, it's a fallback, see? So if you have "\*.example.com IN SRV 0 0 0 .", then an invalid SRV request for totally.invalid.rubbish.example.com receives an answer, just like all the valid requests.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Clever.  Unfortunately after trying this with my DNS server (Bind) the lookup algorithm doesn't fallback to this wildcard on a per record type basis.  Only if there are no matching records of any type will the suggested wildcard approach work.  So even though I have no other SRV records and am doing a lookup for SRV records, a PTR record that happens to match the address I am  looking up will prevent the SRV wildcard from matching.  Thanks.